# UDF/User defined function libreoffice basic with built-in help/tip

Tags: input, macros, basic, udf, libreoffice-calc

I did a function in LibreOffice calc. It works, but I would like to have a conext help/tip capability, like the built in LibreOffice functions.

Example: when I type "=besselk(" it appaears a tip BESSELK(X; N). Using the function wizard a function and arguments description does also appear.
[Besselk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKXyO.png)
[besselk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPKl4.png)

Let's say I have a function to calculte a rectangle area

```
function arearect(a, b)
arearect = a * b
end function
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
function arearect(a, b)
FUNCTION DESCRIPTION "Compute rectangle area"
ARGUMENT DESCRIPTION "base length"
ARGUMENT DESCRIPTION "height"
arearect = a * b
end function
```

so, when I type "=arearect(" the argument description would appear and all descriptors would appear on Function Wizard.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the user-defined function as a [Spreadsheet Add-In](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Spreadsheet_Add-Ins).  Then enter the help text in the `Description` node in the .xcu file that defines the add-in.

For example, I created a function called REVERSE.  Here is my CalcAddIns.xcu file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oor:component-data xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          oor:name="CalcAddIns" oor:package="org.openoffice.Office">
  <node oor:name="AddInInfo">
    <node oor:name="name.JimK.ReverseStringImpl" oor:op="replace">
      <node oor:name="AddInFunctions">
        <node oor:name="reverse" oor:op="replace">
          <prop oor:name="DisplayName"><value xml:lang="en">reverse</value></prop>
          <prop oor:name="Description">
            <value xml:lang="en">Flips a string backwards.  For example "apple" becomes "elppa".</value>
          </prop>
          <prop oor:name="Category"><value>Add-In</value></prop>
          <!-- This won't help, because there is no reverse() in Excel. -->
          <prop oor:name="CompatibilityName"><value xml:lang="en">reverse</value></prop>
          <node oor:name="Parameters">
            <node oor:name="s" oor:op="replace">
              <prop oor:name="DisplayName"><value xml:lang="en">s</value></prop>
              <prop oor:name="Description"><value xml:lang="en">The string to reverse.</value></prop>
            </node>
          </node>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</oor:component-data>
```

An Add-In also requires some other files.  Here is my XCalcFunctions.idl:

```java
#include <com/sun/star/uno/XInterface.idl>

module name { module JimK { module CalcFunctions {

    interface XCalcFunctions
    {
      string reverse( [in] string s );
    };

}; }; };
```

The actual implementation was simple.  I used python:

```py
def reverseString(inString):
    s = unicode(inString)
    # This is extended slice syntax [begin:end:step].  With a step of -1,
    # it will traverse the string elements in descending order.
    return s[::-1]
```

The result:

[image: calc tooltip]

**EDIT**:

There is another piece in Components.py for my extension:

```py
class StringReverserAddIn(unohelper.Base, XCalcFunctions):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx

    @staticmethod
    def factory(ctx):
        return StringReverserAddIn(ctx)

    def reverse(self, inString):
        from lingt.app.calcfunctions import reverseString
        return reverseString(inString)

g_ImplementationHelper.addImplementation(
    StringReverserAddIn.factory,
    "name.JimK.LinguisticTools.ReverseStringImpl",
    ("com.sun.star.sheet.AddIn",),)
```

The file is declared in manifest.xml:

```xml
<!--- The Python code -->
<manifest:file-entry
 manifest:full-path="Components.py"
 manifest:media-type="application/vnd.sun.star.uno-component;type=Python"/>
```

The complete extension: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lingtools.

Comment: Hi. Those files are within the  .ods file?  If not, this will be tricky. Because I want to share the functions within the calc file to people who aren't savvy enough to install a addin.

Comment: The files need to be in a separate .oxt package, not within the .ods file.  Installing an .oxt file basically just requires double-clicking on it, so hopefully most people who know how to work with spreadsheets would be able to do it.  Or could you install it for them, perhaps remotely?

Comment: I will go for the .oxt installation.
But how to generate an .oxt? I know can can put all the files on a zip, then rename as .oxt.
As in your example, what is the name for python code file for reverse? Could you give your .oxt? The online tutorials about extension lack on simplicity, which I think is our case here.

Comment: @Matheus: Added the link to the .oxt in the edited answer.